# Install msi in non admin users

Tags: wix, group-policy

I have created a path rule in Software Restriction Policies to install my msi (C:\temp\my_msi_file.msi). I have tried to install my application in non-admin account. It opens gently and starts installation. While installing it ended with the error "You do not have sufficient privilege to complete this action". In my installer i am accessing database and registry values. I think in this point the installation is fails. Is there anyway to run my msi application without admin privilege? It will be good to set in OS level.
Note: I want to give full access permission only the applications created by me.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file; Select properties; Navigate to security tab; You can see the file permissions. Click edit. Select `system` in the list. Click Apply and Ok. Now you can install the file

Comment: Or try running as the administrator Right Click > Run as administrator